# Google maps: I want to move (pan/tilt) the 360 street view/pictures programmatically using Mouse events (or pointer/touch events)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On [this Google Maps Streetview for example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/streetview-controls), I want to pan and tilt around a picture programmatically using javascript I paste on the browser's console. I want to build a page on a TV that pans and tilts around beautiful scenes based on some input.

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  var canvass = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );

  canvass.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( 'click', {
    pointerId:   0,
    clientX:     100,
    clientY:     390,
    offsetX:     100,
    offsetY:     390,
    screenX:     100,
    screenY:     390,
    button:      -1,
    buttons:     1,
    bubbles:     true,
    cancelable:  true,
    pointerType: "mouse",
    isPrimary:   true,
    isTrusted:   true,
    pressure:    0.5
  } ) );
  canvass.dispatchEvent( new PointerEvent( 'pointerdown', {
    pointerId:   1,
    clientX:     100,
    clientY:     390,
    offsetX:     100,
    offsetY:     390,
    screenX:     100,
    screenY:     390,
    button:      -1,
    buttons:     1,
    bubbles:     true,
    cancelable:  true,
    pointerType: "mouse",
    isPrimary:   true,
    isTrusted:   true,
    pressure:    0.5
  } ) );


  for ( i = 100; i < 400; i += 40 ) {
    var event    = new PointerEvent( 'pointermove', {
      pointerId:   0,
      clientX:     i,
      clientY:     390,
      offsetX:     i,
      offsetY:     390,
      screenX:     i,
      screenY:     390,
      layerX:      i,
      layerY:      390,
      button:      -1,
      buttons:     1,
      bubbles:     true,
      cancelable:  true,
      pointerType: "mouse",
      isPrimary:   true,
      isTrusted:   true,
      view:        window,
      pressure:    0.5
    } )
    event.layerX = i;
    event.layerY = 390;
    canvass.dispatchEvent( event );
  }

  canvass.dispatchEvent( new PointerEvent( 'pointerup', {
    pointerId:   0,
    clientX:     400,
    clientY:     390,
    offsetX:     400,
    offsetY:     390,
    screenX:     400,
    screenY:     390,
    button:      -1,
    buttons:     1,
    bubbles:     true,
    cancelable:  true,
    pointerType: "mouse",
    isPrimary:   true,
    isTrusted:   true,
    pressure:    0.5
  } ) );
```

As you can see in the code above, I tried adding more and more properties but none worked. Firefox was helpful in pointing where in google's "uglified" code the events were sent. I logged the events and compared the true mouse events vs the events I send from the code above. I don't see a big difference. Then I thought `layerX` and `layerY` properties may be the issue and tried to set them in the code above. However, I could not set them and they don't show up when I log the event.

I am stumped and can't think of another way to achieve that. Help is appreciated.

**True Mouse event properties**

```
bubbles: true
button: -1
buttons: 1
cancelable: true
cancelBubble: true
clientX: 435
clientY: 343
composed: true
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
height: 1
isPrimary: true
isTrusted: true
layerX: 435
layerY: 343
ltKey: false
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
mozInputSource: 1
mozPressure: 0.5
offsetX: 0
offsetY: 0
originalTarget: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
pageX: 435
pageY: 343
pointerId: 0
pointerType: "mouse"
pressure: 0.5
rangeOffset: 0
rangeParent: null
region: ""
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 435
screenY: 439
shiftKey: false
srcElement: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
tangentialPressure: 0
target: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
tiltX: 0
tiltY: 0
timeStamp: 1314551
twist: 0
type: "pointermove"
view: Window https://www.google.com/maps/place/Al+Ula/@26.6600113,37.9087448,3a,75y,153.81h,4.79t
```

​**Artificial mouse event properties**

```
bubbles: true
button: -1
buttons: 1
cancelable: true
cancelBubble: true
clientX: 120
clientY: 390
composed: false
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
height: 1
isPrimary: true
isTrusted: false
layerX: 0
layerY: 0
lse
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
mozInputSource: 1
mozPressure: 0.5
offsetX: 120
offsetY: 390
originalTarget: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
pageX: 120
pageY: 390
pointerId: 0
pointerType: "mouse"
pressure: 0.5
rangeOffset: 0
rangeParent: null
region: ""
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 120
screenY: 390
shiftKey: false
srcElement: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
tangentialPressure: 0
target: <canvas id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" width="2880" height="822" style="width: 1440px; height: 411px;" tabindex="-1">
tiltX: 0
tiltY: 0
timeStamp: 1702460
twist: 0
type: "pointermove"
view: null
which: 0
width: 1
x: 120
y: 390
```

Comment: I found [this working example](https://codepen.io/tothebeat/pen/BbhaJ) in 5 seconds (first result of a Google Search for *Streetview auto pan*).

Comment: I've seen these examples before. They are restricted and rely on Google's Maps API (google.maps.*). What I want is to be able to simulate mouse/touch movements on ANY google maps or street maps page. Simulate mouse events sent to the event listeners. 

Why isn't the PointerEvent() the code dispatches equivalent to the one the browser dispatches?

Comment: Get the panorama IDs of those you like and want to feature that way, develop your own solution around the Maps API so that you can see the panoramas that way. What's the point using the console on third-party websites to achieve that?? That just makes no sense, sorry. Also if you can/could access the source images, you could build your own solution, without the use of the Maps API.

Comment: I tried to get the panorama ID for this beautiful 360 picture (https://goo.gl/maps/PGm5jppaPztzQXmv7) but couldn't. Can you figure it out?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've extracted the panorama ID from my comment above and added it to the sample code that Google Developer help provides. It is here https://jsfiddle.net/eqhj3vcp/ and all what I see is a blank panorama. I will be glad if you could point me to a way to pan/tilt this panorama https://goo.gl/maps/PGm5jppaPztzQXmv7

Comment: There are undocumented ways of getting the panorama id from the URL. What you do have though in the URL is the earth coordinates (26.6600113, 37.9087448 in your example) so you can request the closest panorama with the API: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/zjb8yrp6/ If you need the smooth animation like in the example I pasted earlier, then I suppose you need the WebGL approach.

Comment: You can also request the panorama by its ID but the ID you used in your fiddle doesn't correspond to the pano you mentioned earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ac9sf730/

Comment: @MrUpsidown Excellent. This is exactly the control I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@MrUpsidown has demonstrated another equally good approach using Google's Map API. Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/jsr3z8e6/

```
var map;
var panorama;
var panoramaService;
var streetView;
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(26.6600113, 37.9087448);

function initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  panoramaService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  var panoramaOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);

  map.setStreetView(panorama);

  streetView = map.getStreetView();
  runPanoramaService();
}

function runPanoramaService() {
  panoramaService.getPanorama({
    pano: 'F:AF1QipMUgQD1VGebAWOdIlFCavG1hd76JH9QxjaIUXTl'
  }, function(streetViewPanoramaData, streetViewStatus) {

    if (streetViewStatus == "OK") {

      streetView.setPosition(streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng);
      streetView.setVisible(true);
      spinIt();
    }
  });

}

function spinIt() {

  var pov = panorama.getPov();

  setInterval(function() {

    pov.heading += 0.1;
    pov.pitch = 20 * Math.sin(20*pov.heading/360);
    if (pov.heading > 360) {
      pov.heading -= 360;
    }

    panorama.setPov(pov);

  }, 2);
};

initialize();
```